# Advice on fixing torn metal base connecting to stem of office chair without professional welding

Tags: furniture, welding

I need advice on fixing torn metal base connecting to stem of office chair without professional welding. The cost of welding is more than the chair. Would J-B weld or other options fix the 'tear' in the metal. Please see image
[image: picture of torn metal base of office chair]

Comment: ...it's so poorly designed that solid steel tore. No wonder it's cheap. None of the epoxy products are actually "as strong as steel", much less stronger. I think I found a titanium-filled-epoxy product that was about half as strong as low grade steel once upon a time.

Comment: Take the base off the chair and take to local garage/auto mechanic.  Job done in five minutes if you can leave it there for when they have the time.  Ten bucks and a beer should do it.

Comment: _Can_ it be fixed with epoxy? Sure! Will it last long or be safe? Maybe, maybe not, tending toward "not". If it's just a temporary fix while you shop for a new chair, go for it.

Comment: @FreeMan - I wish this could be counted as answer and not a comment because I did just that and have a chair again!

Answer (score 2):

In the interest of safety, get a new chair. You cannot rely on commonly available epoxies (or other adhesives) to take the place of a weld on such a high stress joint especially since the available surface area for the joint is small.

Comment: Correct. When if you consider that it was welded, and the weld broke, that's as strong as it's going to get!

Answer (score 2):

If you like the chair and it is comfortable, you can replace the mechanism. Measure the distance between the holes and then look for a [swivel chair mechanism](https://amzn.to/3HHVNdZ) to match.

If you don't particularly like the chair, just get a new chair.

Do *not* try to fix the actual component. It won't last.

Comment: If finding a base with pre-drilled holes in precisely the right locations is difficult, find one with a _larger_ base plate and drill new mounting holes to match the current locations.

Comment: I'll check out your link. The chair bolts are 5 1/2" distance width and 7" distance length - very uncommon. annoying